# How to receive data of a td element in the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Modify Index Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/static/css/header.css" />'>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script
 src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table {
 table-layout: fixed;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

th {
 text-align: center;
}

#serviceSelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#serviceSelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}

#removeSelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#removeSelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}

#123 {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
}

p {
 font: bold;
}

.editrow {
 border: 3px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="../shared/header.jsp">
  <jsp:param value="modifyIndexOrder" name="currentPage" />
 </jsp:include>
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="updateIndexOrder"
  method=POST id="form2">
  <div class="table-responsive12">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight"
  id="tab_logic">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th style="width: 20%">IndexOrder</th>
    <th style="width: 20%">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 20%">CatKey</th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>  
 </table>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight"
    id="submittable">
    <tr id="submit123">
     <td colspan="3" align="center">
      <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(function() {
   loadTable();
   $("#tab_logic").sortable({
    items : "tr:not(th)",
    helper : "clone",
    update : function() {
     alert("success");
    }
   }).disableSelection();
  // print();
   
  });
  
  function loadTable(){
    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",  
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false,
    url : "modifyIndex",
    success : function(data) {
     loadData(data);
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }

   }); 
  }
  function loadData(data){
   alert("success");
   var htm="<tr><th style='width:20%'>IndexOrder</th><th style='width:20%'>Name</th><th style='width:20%'>CatKey</th></tr>";
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   {
    htm+="<tr><td name='io"+i+"'>"+data[i].indexOrder+"</td><td name='na"+i+"'>"+data[i].name+"</td><td name='ca"+i+"'>"+data[i].catKey+"</td></tr>";
    
   }
   $("#tab_logic").html(htm);
  }
  function print()
  {
   var order = $("#tab_logic td");
   var i = 1;
   var col = 1;
   order.each(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(t);
    
   });
  } 

 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a table in a form which doesn't have any input field but only a table that displays data . i want that on submitting the form i should be able to read the data of the td element of the table in my controller .

Something like `request.getParameter("td_name")` . I read that name is not a valid attribute for td . SO in this case how can i get the data of the td elements in my controller.

Comment: What is the method you are trying right now? Are you submitting the form through jquery?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code ? You can use ajax and data attribute

Comment: Do it via javascript/jquery, store the values in a variable, and send it via hidden input in the form

Comment: I have posted the code . And i have loads of columns so sending it through AJAX data section isn't feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through your table and get all of your tr's or td's, for example:

```
var products = [];
$('#table tbody tr').each(function (index, tr) {
    var product = {
        Id: Number($(tr).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()),,
    }

    products.push(product);
});

$.post('/Url/Post', { products: products }, function (response, status) {
    console.log(response);

    if (status === 'success') {
        alert('Success.');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see that it is getting me the value .But how do i process it in the server side . request.getParameter("products") is not working

Comment: I think this should work: $products = $_POST['products'];

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding id attribute to your td

example : `<td id="mytd">This is some value</td>`

Now on your java script you could do something like this:

```
var tdvalue = document.getElementById ( "mytd" ).innerText;
```

or in jQuery

```
var tdvalue = $("#mytd").text();
```

now all you have to do is pass `tdvalue` to your request :)